# Entity Framework core bulk Extensions: BulkInsertOrUpdate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have requirement in entityfremawork core bulk extensions feature.
when we are using  _context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(Customers);
I have not created any primary key on sql customer table. So i am trying to  map target columns(Insert or update)  externally like
below

```
context.BulkInsertOrUpdate()
  .MatchTargetOn(x => x.CustomerId)
  .MatchTargetOn(x => x.CustomerName)
  .Commit(db.Database.Connection);
```

Is there any way in ef core bulk extensions

Comment: So, you have chosen third party extension which supports matching only via PK.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution if library do not support such matching. So consider to change third party library to another or wait for feature implementation.

BTW, I have created this bridge between `linq2db` and `EF Core` [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), so if you have no other options, this one should work.

```cs
context.Customers
   .ToLinqToDBTable()
   .Merge()
   .Using(entities)
   .On((t, s) => t.CustomerId == s.CustomerId || t.CustomerName == s.CustomerName)
   .InsertWhenNotMatched()
   .UpdateWhenMatched()
   .Merge();
```

Check overloads of `InsertWhenNotMatched` and `UpdateWhenMatched` - here you can customize which fields should be inserted or updated even based on values from target table.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but covers easily scenarios such as custom keys. The `InsertOrUpdate` is equivalent to `BulkMerge`.

Example:

```
context.BulkMerge(list,  options => options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = c => 
    new { c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName });
```

Here is an online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lzbh2H

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Magnan,

Comment: I am trying to use https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions and downloaded EFCore.BulkExtensions (nuget 3.3.1).Please let us know this nuget 3.3.1 package is free or we have to purchase license.

Comment: @user1926055. It's free but is not working for you :)

Comment: @user1926055, the package made by borisdj is a different package than our library. Here is our package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore/ , there is a free trial, so you can try it by simply downloading and using the NuGet package.