# How to add/update/delete data in EF core 6 like MERGE statement in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to add or update or delete rows according to conditions in EF core 6 like 'merge' statement in sql server?

I want to add or update rows into a table according to a condition and delete the existing rows from the table that not match a condition.

like in sql server:

```sql
MERGE MemberTarget T
USING MemberSource S ON T.CustomerID=S.CustomerID and T.WorkerID=S.WorkerID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE;
```

Comment: You can do that via extensions, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66105196/10646316)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a type-safe way in EF Core currently. However, you can run arbitrary SQL commands using `ExecuteSqlRaw` / `ExecuteSqlInterpolated`. For details, see MSDN docs: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating#bulk-updates)

If you want to keep it type-safe, you may consider [LINQ to DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db), which [supports generating merge statements](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/merge/Merge-API-Description.html). You can use this library as a complement to EF Core as it [integrates with EF Core](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) nicely.